# Django Passwords don't match after changing hasher, can't log in

Tags: django, hash, passwords

I need to store my passwords in plain text in the database(it is just a Django practice project). That's why I added a password hasher:

```
class PlainTextPassword(BasePasswordHasher):
    algorithm = "plain"

    def salt(self):
        return ''

    def encode(self, password, salt):
        assert salt == ''
        return password

    def verify(self, password, encoded):
        return password == encoded

    def safe_summary(self, encoded):
        return OrderedDict([
            (_('algorithm'), self.algorithm),
            (_('hash'), encoded),
        ])
```

It works fine. But the problem is that I can't log in with these passwords, my theory is that Django passes already hashed password to verification and that's why passwords don't match. I'm using allauth lib. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: you can simply use md5 to encrypt your password and store it on your db. for more information read the official docs here -- > https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/auth/hashers/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need plain text passwords.